# How to use the Chromium Spellchecker with other languages than English

Tags: chromium, spell-checking

I would like to know how to select other languages than English when using the chromium spell checker. When I right click the text-boxes and select other language (e.g. Portuguese), English remains the language in use by the spellchecker.

Thanks,
Pedro

Comment: There's a bug description in launchpad. If this bug also affects you please tick "This bug also affects me" if you do have a launchpad account. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/888093

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After choosing the new language, copy the text you are editing and duplicate the tab. The chosen language will be used by the spellchecker in the newly open tab.